# json object formation gets wrong

Tags: javascript, json

I have following json string saved in DB, while converting it to Json Object sometimes created the nested properties object. And moreover this is issue is very much random not always comes. Most of times works fine.

***Json String in DB:***

```js
[{"reason": "ABC.", "amount": 25 }, 
 {"reason": "XYZ", "amount": 52 }, 
 {"reason": "PQR", "amount": 20 }]
```

***Wrong json Object format created :***

```js
[{"reason":0,"amount":{"reason":0,"amount" : {"reason":"ABC","amount":25}}},
 {"reason":1,"amount":{"reason":1,"amount":{"reason":"XYZ","amount":52}}},
 {"reason":2,"amount":{"reason":2,"amount":{"reason":"PQR","amount":20]


CODE:
```

Receives the result from DB and then create the object of the model:

```
let row = null;
if (result.rows.length > 0) {
row = result.rows[0];
obj= new Summary(
   row.get('invalid_reason_summary'));

return obj;
}
```

Class model    :

```
function Summary(reasons) {
  this._reasons = reasons ? JSON.parse(reasons) : null;
}
```

I have used `JSON.parse` to convert from string to json object.

Comment: make sure result is correct before JSON.parse , check using console.log

Comment: Yeah did it!! and the result before parse is correct, as I mentioned this is very much random issue for me.

Comment: Please include that code that deals with the original response up to the point where you produce the output. And if it is your own code that builds the JSON (server sided), also include that part.

Comment: I have added the code in question

Comment: I see you have `JSON.parse(result.rows[0].get('invalid_reason_summary'))`. What is with `get()`? Can you explain what type of value `result` is as I'm a little confused? If `result` is a JSON string then just do `JSON.parse(result)`.

Comment: What technology stack are you using in your app?

Comment: we are using the node.js + Cassandra DB at backend, and result.rows[0].get('invalid_reason_summary')).  is to fetch the value of the column from selected row from the Cassandra DB